# Symfony2: How to use validators of a different Bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to use the validators of FOSUserBundle in my own form, but I don't know how to set up the validator.yml. It currently looks like this:

```
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    constraints:
        - FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique:
            property: usernameCanonical
        - FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique:
            property: emailCanonical
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank: ~
        email:
            - Email: ~
            - NotBlank: ~
        mandant:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Type: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Mandant
```

But this results in the following PHP error:

```
[05-Mar-2012 14:47:56 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[05-Mar-2012 14:47:56 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() W:\redacted\symfony_webfrontend\app\console:0
[05-Mar-2012 14:48:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\UserBundle\ValidatorUnique' not found in W:\redacted\symfony_webfrontend\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\FileLoader.php on line 73
```

It looks like the class path is wrong but I can't find any documentation on how to use validators of a different bundle in my own validators.yml...

Comment: Have a loog at the services defined by the FOS User Bundle. It might be that this validators are services and you need to use the service id instead of the real class name. Just a wild guess though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it actually works now because I tried this before, but this seems the way to go:

```
namespaces:
    FOSUserBundle: FOS\UserBundle\Validator\

Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    constraints:
        - "FOSUserBundle:Unique":
            property: usernameCanonical
        - "FOSUserBundle:Unique":
            property: emailCanonical
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank: ~
        email:
            - Email: ~
            - NotBlank: ~
        Mandant:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Type: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Mandant
```

Comment: As per Boo's comment, originally you was attemting to directly access the validators, this time your (correctly) using the services instances of those validators.

Comment: Wow, for me it still looks like I'm just telling Symfony which class in which namespace I need... I just declare a shorthand (FOSUserBundle) for the namespace and continue using that instead of the full namespace.

Comment: Update! FOSUserBundle no longer has a Unique Validator to do this: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/7dffdd8f095b9ee4a9f8fdd3a8e1e3ee69450cf1